# xpediter putting breakpoint in called program

Tags: debugging, cobol

i try to debug program from called in main program in COBOL mainframe environment. 
How can i put a breakpoint in IZLP0851 [image]

I am using xpediter tools for debugging.

Comment: Have you ever noticed how many IBM programs, routines, macros, messages, etc start with the letter `I`. I'm sure there's a recommendation somewhere not to do that. Even if there isn't, it is a distinctly bad idea. Unless deeply ingrained in your systems, suggest to your boss that programs should never start with an I. Is there no-one at your site who knows how to us Xpediter? Not even your technical staff? Do you not have ready copies of the manuals, with examples?

Answer (score 0):

I have found anwser. When write "`int IZLP0851`" i can debug this subprogram. and return with `F6` to main program.